# Claim and fix an unauthorized listing in Google Maps/Places

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business

One of our branch offices has had a Google Maps/Places listing created and verified by a staff member who was not authorized (not the IT or Communications & Marketing departments); the office has since complained that they get lots of phone calls intended for the head office based on the Google Search or Maps results.

We've created a listing for our head office & had it verified by postcard (though it still seems to show as an "Unverified listing"); trying to edit the branch office listing when logged in with the (corporate) account that owns our correct listing results in an error saying we don't own it.

How can we have the branch office listing removed/corrected so it doesn't show as the top result?

Answer (score 1):

Persistence paid off - by having a more recently verified listing (address, phone & website) and reporting the bad entry, we were able to have the other entry removed.